get computed style with selenium
I need to get a computed style attribute (pointer-events) which I can see in the Browser dev-tools, as highlighted in screenshot. Things linke element.getAttribute("style") don't give me the computed styles. Ho can I get them with selenium and java?


In C# we have the method entity.GetCssValue("color") to get computed CSS values. Hope this hint gives you a solution direction.
See https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue(java.lang.String)

In Java it's entity.getCSSValue("pointer-events");  Thanks
